# Paypal Express Checkout Japanese Zipcodes

Tags: paypal

How should Japanese zipcodes be handed over to paypal (using Website Payment Standard)? When 144-0043 is supplied in zip variable with Tokyo as a city, Paypal refuses to accept this.

Comment: How exactly did you code the zip code field?

Comment: As an input with name "zip" within a form POSTing to "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned you are trying to POSTing data to "paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", it is more likely you are integrating PayPal Website Payment Standard instead of Express Checkout. Anyway, PayPal does not check the validation of shipping address to Japan, as long as you have passed the data in correct set. Please refer to below example which should successfully pass to PayPal.

```
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="haneda">
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="1-2-3">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="ootaku">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="tokyo">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="144-0043">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="JP">
```

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU

Comment: Thank you for this. I was missing "state". After handing over any foo value for state everything seems to work fine. Have corrected the integration name in the question not to confuse others.

Answer (score 0):

With Express Checkout you need to pass certain parameters in your SetExpressCheckout Request along with your Payment Request:

Include the following in your Payment Request:

The country taken from the LocaleCode parameter passed by the merchant.

This comes directly from the PayPal Developer Site :

[LocaleCode and Country Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/locale_codes/)

```
CountryCode = JP
LocaleCode = ja_JP
LocaleCode = en_US
```

Here is another field that you can send through to let the PayPal server know that you are sending international shipping: 
 
This comes from the PayPal Developer Site:

[DoExpressCheckout Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

> **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_BUCKETCATEGORYTYPE**   (Optional) The category of a
>   payment. It is one of the following values:
>
> ```
> 1 - International shipping
> 2 - Local delivery
> ```

Make certain you are sending the shipToCountryCode as well. This is additional information on shipping from the PayPal Developer Site:

> **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPTOZIP**
>     U.S. ZIP code or other country-specific
>   postal code. It is required if using a U.S. shipping address and may
>   be required for other countries. Character length and limitations: 20
>   single-byte characters.

The final portion is the ShiptToCountry Code:

> **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE**
>     Country code. It is required if
>   using a shipping address. Character length and limitations: 2
>   single-byte characters.